# Display HAS_MANY relation data in DetailView yii2

Tags: yii2, has-many, detailsview

I wants to know is it possible to display one to many relation data in `detailview`. For example a user can have more than one email registered. So is it possible to display all the emails registered by one user in `detailview`.

I have tried something like below but its not working.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'username',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'location',
        'is_active:boolean',
        [
            'label' => 'Emails',
            'value' => ArrayHelper::map(
                UserEmails::find()
                    ->where(['user_id'=>$model->id])
                    ->orderBy('id')
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all(),
                'id', 'email')
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

I am getting error anyway but i wants to know is it possible? and what am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

In DetailView, item's value can be only a value. So you can prepopulate that value.

```
$email = implode(',',UserEmails::find()->select('email')->where(['user_id'=>$model->id])->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all())
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'username',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'location',
            'is_active:boolean',
            [
                'label' => 'Emails',
                'value' => $emails
            ],

        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model contains `hasMany()` function, for example `getCategories()` or anything, you can just specify the very minimalist code to your DetailView. Also, I am using a clojure.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'categories',
    'value' => function ($model)
    {
        return implode(', ', $model->getCategories()->select('label')->column());
    }
],
```